# get_the_post_thumbnail_url does not return anything if image size is set

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, post-thumbnails

I want to display the post-thumbnail image in the header using `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` with defined size, however if I am using it without specifying the size, like  `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` it is displaying the thumbnail img, but if I am using it like: `get_the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail')` nothing is shown.

my code in the header.php is:

```
<?php
function vkb_header_style() {
         if (has_post_thumbnail() and is_singular()) {
             $vkb_thumbnail_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail');
             echo 'background-image: url(' . $vkb_thumbnail_url . ');';
         } else {
            storefront_header_styles(); 
         }
     }
?>

<header id="masthead" class="site-header vkb-header" role="banner" style=" <?php vkb_header_style(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter for [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) is the post ID or post object, and not the image size which is actually the second parameter.

So:

```php
// Instead of this:
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( 'thumbnail' )

// You should use:
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail' ) // pass a post ID
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_post(), 'thumbnail' )   // or post object

// Or you can pass a null to use the current post:
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( null, 'thumbnail' )
```